# Disable windows help and support

Tags: windows-7

I need to disable that windows help that comes up with the `F1` key

Disabling the shortcut is also a solution

P.S.:
There is no such a function as *Help and Support* service on Windows 7

I presume that the answer could lie on the Group Policy editor

Comment: See this....https://www.top-password.com/blog/disable-f1-key-from-opening-help-in-windows/

Comment: Yes. That did it ! Problem solved. Close the thread

Answer (score 3):

**Moab** answered the question, but I will paste it here in case it gets lost.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win64]
@=""
```